# OData EnableQuery is not working in production

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have an Odata function which return a collection of entity set(User) like below

```
[HttpGet, ODataRoute("getTopUsers(userId={userId})")]
[EnableQuery(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.Top)]
public IHttpActionResult GetTopUsers(int? userId)
{
    IList<User> users = new List<User>()
    {
        new User() { Id=1, Name ="first" },
        new User() { Id=2, Name ="Second" },
        new User() { Id=2, Name ="third" }
    };
    return Ok(users);
}
```

But when I invoked the function with

*productionUrl/getTopUsers(userId={userId})?$top=1*

It always return all the users meaning not applying the top query but the same is working in development environment.

Am I missed anything? Any idea will be helpful.

I updated the packages of

Microsoft.AspNet.OData => 5.9.1

Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData => 5.7.0

Comment: I got all the response but the problem is $top query is not applied

Comment: Firstly just a disclaimer.. I am not very familiar with oData but two things are problematic here.. to leverage the true power of OData, you need to be working with an `iQueryable` which will allow for the query expression tree to be built up before performing a database call. Secondly, you are not filtering the `users` collection based on the query parameters at all. Please see the `Invoking Query Options Directly` section on this page: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options

Comment: @adaam: I will check with IQueryable, now I am expecting a filtering from OData instead of fetching the queries using ODataQueryOptions

Comment: So.. just confirming.. it works perfectly in dev but not in production !! That said, have you compared the IIS settings, prod web-config and tried doing some sort of logging ??

Comment: In my dev environment, I didn't done any thing in web config. From production environment I got all result but it's not responsive with query. I need to check some thing is there with iis.

Comment: @adaam: Returning the data as users.AsQueryable() makes no difference